# Error while deploying mysql using persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hi guys i am trying to Create the MySQL manifest file with nfs-mysql.yaml using the below content:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /data
    server: xxxxxxxxxxxx
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql-nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
  requests:
    storage: 500Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql-wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql-wordpress
    product: mysql
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql-wordpress
spec:
  selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: mysql-wordpress
    product: mysql
    strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: mysql-wordpress
      product: mysql
  spec:
    containers:
      - image: mysql
        name: mysql-container
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: wordpress
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysql-secret-password
            key: password
        ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql-storage
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
    volumes:
      - name: mysql-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mysql-nfs
```

but It's throwing this error when I Try to run the yaml file:

**error validating "nfs-mysql.yaml": error validating data: [unknown object type "nil" in Deployment.spec.selector.matchLabels.strategy, ValidationError(Deployment.spec): unknown field "spec" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false**

I don't understand the error can someone help me with this error?

Comment: any update on this ? feel free to update the status of question if resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

There us that your YAML file having the issue with **strategy**

```
spec:
  selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: mysql-wordpress
    product: mysql
    strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
  metadata:
```

it should be like

```
strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
```

it should not be part the selector like you have mentioned so there is indentation issue with that, you can use below on for ref

```
spec:
  replicas: 4
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  minReadySeconds: 5
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
```

even your **selector** having the issue so make you follow the proper indentation path in **YAML**.

Refer the official doc for more : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/